# SQLite.swift and SQLiteCipher.swift Anyone successfully using?

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlcipher

Is anyone successfully using SQLiteCipher.swift?

SQLite.swift installs and works with cocoapods.

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLiteCipher.swift suggests **cocoapods install:**

use_frameworks!

pod 'SQLiteCipher.swift',
  git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLiteCipher.swift.git'

and this results in:

[!] Unable to find a specification for 'SQLiteCipher.swift'.

**The doco then suggests manual install:**

Drag the SQLiteCipher.xcodeproj file into your own project. (Submodule or clone the project first.)

In your target’s General tab, click the + button under Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Select the appropriate SQLiteCipher.framework for your platform.

Click Add.

This results in No such module SQLiteCipher.

I've tried every "no such module" fix on the internet ...  nada

Any insight appreciated!  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'readme' file is outdated.
I ran into the same issue and here is solution (it worked for me, but according to discussion it's not perfect):

```
pod 'SQLiteCipher.swift',
  git: 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git',
  branch: 'swift-2'
```

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/196